# Why do I need print() when calling a function here?

Tags: python

I've spent more time than I should trying to solve a code problem this way:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.w = width
        self.h = height
    def area(self):
       # return area
       return(self.w * self.h)

w = int(input())
h = int(input())
    
obj = Rectangle(w, h)
#call the function
obj.area()
```

I'm trying to call the area function like they call a function in this example:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

    def bark(self):
        print("Woof!")

fido = Dog("Fido", "brown")
print(fido.name)
fido.bark()
```

But after giving up and looking at some answers and at a similar problem on a different site, people all use this instead:

```
print(obj.area())
```

Can somebody explain why I have to use print? It seems redundant but apparently it isn't, because without it, I get no output.

Comment: `print` is how you print output.  The `Dog` example calls `print` inside the `bark` function, which is why it prints something whenever `bark()` is called.  Since your `area()` function calculates the area but doesn't print it, you still need to call `print` on that value if you want to print it out.

Comment: Please make clear what you are trying to achieve, and what behavior your experiencing.

Comment: Only in the interactive interpreter would you *see* the area by running `obj.area()` by itself. The method only returns the area; it's the interactive interpreter that subsequently prints the return value for you to see.

Comment: Programs in general (not just Python programs) don't provide output unless you tell them to.

Comment: OK thanks guys, I'm also generally still struggling with the difference between return and print, but I guess this helps understand the difference between making something visible to a human user or not.

Comment: @Samwise So wouldn't it be better to use print instead of return for the area function? However, I've understood from other materials that functions go together with return and not print, but maybe I'm just wrong by thinking that

Comment: The important thing (and this is getting into high level "how to write good code" stuff that's somewhat orthogonal to "how does the language work") is for a function to do exactly what its purpose is and ideally nothing else.  If the purpose of the function is to compute the area, it should `return` the area, and let the caller decide what to do with it -- maybe `print` it, maybe do some further calculation with it.  If your function only ever `print`s its result it's impossible to do anything else with it.  If it `print`s *and* `return`s then it's impossible to get rid of the extra output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in order to help you understand the reason, it is important to understand the difference between a method that returns a value and one that has no return statement.

Firstly, ALL functions return a value. Even those that don't have an explicit return statement (such as your `bark` method). If no return statement is passed, the method returns value `None`. You can test this by doing:

```
print(fido.bark())  # prints None
```

Now in your `area` method you are returning a value, not printing it. That is why you have to print the value that gets returned in order to visualize it. That is the difference between the two methods. One returns the actual value, while the other one prints the value and returns None.

Hope that answers your question :) Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I guess I understand what was wrong with my area method, but I still struggle with why the ''None'' happens in the bark case. Because the bark method uses print instead of return?

Comment: Sure. Let me follow up on this other question: `def some_method(): pass` This is a method that does nothing. It still returns None.  So a method will ALWAYS return a value. So it's not about the print. You can have anything in that method. But if you have a `return` statement in there it will return that value. If you don't have a return statement it returns None. It's as simple as that. Here's more documentation to help guide you through this: https://www.askpython.com/python/python-return-statement
Good luck :)